# Is it possible to hide a menu in IE8?

Tags: drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8, zurb-foundation

I'm having trouble with a drop-down menu from the Foundation framework in IE8 and I'm wondering if it is possible to hide an element if the user is using IE8.

Maybe making a simpler menu for IE users is easier than making the drop-down menu work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I approve of your solution ( fix it! ), but you can achieve what you're looking to achieve with conditional comments.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
#yourElemId {
   display: none;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I will try, thanks. It's just a quick fix to have more time to fix the real problem.